# What is a word which describes something you are looking for

Tags: meaning, word-choice, american-english, synonyms

The word would fit within the following context:

> I found the ______ of my search.

I know there there is a simple word which describes an object which is being searched for, but I just can't remember what it was.

Comment: Normally I'd use "object" in the above sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Quarry* to use a hunting metaphor, *object* to be more literal.

Answer (score 3):

*Target* or *object*. It is what you are aiming at or looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Quaesitum is defined as something sought after, if you want to be fancy :)

> That which is sought; the answer to a problem.

from: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/quaesitum)

> : something sought for : end, objective
>
> *our intuition that one of the ideas … is, at last, our quaesitum*— William James

from: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quaesitum)

Comment: This would be improved by including a dictionary reference for the definition.